# Count Elements in Array Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, count, reduce

I have the following JSON Object below. What would be an efficient manner of counting shifts and departments in a way that the info is displayed as the following:

```
shift 1: 10
shift 2: 15

shift 1 & Carton-Pack: 5
shift 1 & Picking: 3
etc.
```

It's just that I'm new to javascript, and I'm afraid I might be over-complicating things.

JSON Object

```
[
{"shift":2,"department":"Pallet-Pack"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":3,"department":"Inventory"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Receiving"},
{"shift":3,"department":"Equipment"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Receiving"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Carton-Pack"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Receiving"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Returns"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Receiving"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Receiving"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Pallet-Pack"},
{"shift":2,"department":"Picking"},
{"shift":1,"department":"Carton-Pack"}]
```

Comment: `I'm afraid I might be over-complicating things.` Post the code you think is too complicated and we can see if it is or not

Comment: well, hopefully you're using JSON.parse to make an object, and then, use array reduce method to create your output object ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry,  I'm doing this on a phone and can't check it, but it's about how I would do it.

```
counts_by_shift = shifts.reduce((counts, s) => {
  if (!counts[s.shift]) {
    counts[s.shift] = {}
    counts[s.shift]._total = 0
  }
  if (!counts[s.shift][s.department]) counts[s.shift][s.department] = 0
  counts[s.shift][s.department]++
  counts[s.shift]._total++
  return counts
}, {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(counts_by_shift))
```

Comment: You're missing the total per shift.